# For any $x\in \mathbb{N}$ does there exist $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2x+1+2m, 2x+1+4m$ are both prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Could someone please give me a proof (or counter example) for this (I believe it is true):

> For any $x$ (Whole Number) there exists some $m$ (Also Whole) such that $2x+1+2m$ and $2x+1+4m$ are both prime.

An equivalent is for any odd $n$ there exists some even $y$ such that $n+y$ and $n+2y$ are both prime. I am pretty sure a proof would be based around Dirichlet's Theorem.

Comment: any odd except 1

Comment: @hardmath but there is no $x : 2x + 1 = 1$.

Comment: $0 \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @ritwiksinha Depends on your definition of $\Bbb N$. It is in no way established convention that $0\notin \Bbb N$.

Comment: An equivalent question is: for any odd $n$, does there exist a solution to the linear equation $2y-z=n$ where both $y$ and $z$ are prime. This is probably as hard as the Goldach conjecture (which asserts that for any even $n$, there exists a solution to the linear equation $y+z=n$ where both $y$ and $z$ are prime).

Comment: [Green Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem) implies that there are **infinitely** many prime numbers $n$ such that there is even $y$ with $n$, $n+y$, and $n+2y$ are all primes.

Comment: Whether the natural numbers contain $0$ is a matter of definition, and different definitions are more convenient in different contexts. Let everyone be assured, though, that this one detail is not at all the most important part of the problem as stated.

Comment: @i707107: this nicely solves the OP for certain primes $n$, but does not solve it in general.

Comment: Dickson's conjecture seems to imply the claim.

Comment: Not quite yet. Green Tao theorem implies infinitely many 3-term arithmetic progression consisted of all primes. That's why I stated **infinitely** many prime numbers $n$. But, OP's claim is for **all** odd $n$.

Comment: The conjecture is true for $1\le n\le 2,166,701$ and an $y\le 1,986$ always exists in this range.

Comment: The conjecture is true for $1\le n\le 6,374,879$ and in this range, an $y\le 2,190$ doing the job always exists.

Comment: Thanks for testing the conjecture and it does seem that Dickson's conjecture is related to it. But then again Dickson's Conjecture implies many conjectures (like twin-prime, Sophia Germain, etc.).  By the way, I haven't heard this anywhere, I made this "conjecture" myself. I feel as though their should exist some simple proof.

Comment: Also equivalent: Given some n (odd), there exists some prime z, so that the average of n and z is another prime, y. But that equivalent looks trivial.

Comment: @Peter assuming you used Mathematica to test this problem, could you comment the code below? I am trying to learn Mathematica and any references for tutorials would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @mtheorylord I used PARI/GP. For such purposes, it is much easier to use, and the main thing, it is free.